# PowerApps How can I disable and enable different dropdowns based on different listbox items selected

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, common-data-service

I have a listbox in PowerApps and I need to enable different dropdowns based on each selection of listbox item. I have one dropdown for each listbox items.

I tried the following code on my dropdowns, but it doesn't work and give error *, + is expected at this point in formula

below is the formula I wrote in DisplayMode of the dropdowns:

```
ForAll(ListBox1_1.SelectedItems, If(ThisRecord.Name="Offce ABC",DisplayMode.Edit,DisplayMode.Disabled));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this depending on how your Dropdown `Items` are setup.

**Assuming...**

1. There is somekind of relationship between the `Items` in the Listbox and the `Items` in each Dropdown
2. Each Dropdown `Items` is a Collection (or a filtered part of a Collection)

**...you can use the following logic for the `DisplayMode` property of the Dropdowns:**

```
If(
    IsEmpty(
        Filter(lbox1.SelectedItems, Value in col1.field)
    ),
    DisplayMode.Disabled, 
    DisplayMode.Edit
)
```

**Example in action:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks, for your Answer, could you please provide example, as my problem is that when I select a selection from listbox for example 1 and then I should say if listbox item 1 is selected enable dropdown1 which data source is coming from common data service. and when listbox item 2 is also selected it should enable another dropdown2 which is also data is coming from common data service.

Comment: values in dropdown are totally different, from the values in listbox.

Answer (score 1):

Again, there are a few ways of doing this depending on how your Dropdown Items are setup.

**Assuming now...**

1. There is **NO** relationship between the Items in the Listbox and the Items in each Dropdown

...you can use the following logic for the DisplayMode property of the Dropdowns:

```
If(
    Or(
        "1" in lbox1_1.SelectedItems,
        "2" in lbox1_1.SelectedItems,
        "3" in lbox1_1.SelectedItems
    ),
    DisplayMode.Edit, 
    DisplayMode.Disabled
)
```

...where "1", "2", etc. are the options in the Listbox `Items` property.

**Example in action:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Answer, can you try populating data from a common data services, when I put your logic it doesn't work, it doesn't accept listbox1.SelectedItems and give error. but when I put listbox1.SelectedItems.Name the error goes out but the logic doesn't work

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: I want exactly what you did, the only thing is try using listbox source as common data service table/entity as a source

Comment: I don't use CDS. You'll have to try different combinations on your own until it works.

Comment: I gived you app vote, but I can't accept it as answer, as it doesn't work with common data service source for the listbox

Comment: Instead of `.SelectedItems` try `.Selected.Name`.